# robots.txt file

Tags: robots.txt

I have a url that I like to restrict the search engines from going to:

Is the following acceptable:

```
    User-agent: *
    Disallow: https://mysite.com/
```

or do I need to put something more like:

```
    User-agent: *
    Disallow: https://mysite.com/index.aspx
```

or would I just put:

```
    User-agent: *
    Disallow: /index.aspx
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The last one is enough. You don't need the whole URL, if you transfer you robots.txt to another website you have to change this file aswell, and that's not what you want. But you do need to start with a `/` which means it's the root of your domain.

Or you can do this:

Disallow ALL

```
User-agent: *
Disallow: /
```

Disallow 1 page

```
User-agent: *
Disallow: /index.php
```

Disallow 1 directory

```
User-agent: *
Disallow: /dirname/
```

Disallow 2 pages and 2 directories

```
User-agent: *
Disallow: /index.php
Disallow: /subpage.php
Disallow: /dirname/
Disallow: /otherdirname/
```

Allow 1 page (only index.php)

```
User-agent: *
Disallow: /~index.php
```

Comment: Have another question. If a site is currently being indexed, how long does it take for robots.txt to take effect if I disallow a url that is currently being indexed on Google

Comment: Depends on how many times a (day/week/month) Google check's out your website. It is not defined, this site (stackoverflow) is checked every X minutes, but sites that just started it can take up to 1 month or more. I can't really tell.